# why everyone process epoll event with an order of read, write, error?

Tags: c++, c, linux, open-source, epoll

I have read many open source code like nginx, redis, uwsgi，I find almost everyone process epoll event when epoll_wait return with an order read, write and error what What would happen if I process in any order，such as write，read and error?
the most of process is below, I write it in pseudo code:

```
nfds = epoll_wait(epfd, interested_events, event_size, timeout);
if (nfds < 0) {
   handle_error()
}

for (i=0; i < nfds; ++i) {
    if (interested_events[i] & READ_EVENT) process_read(interested_events[i]);
    if (interested_events[i] & WRITE_EVENT) process_write(interested_events[i]);
    if (interested_events[i] & ERROR_EVENT) process_(interested_events[i]);
}
```

Comment: Then your code will process the writes before the reads before the errors. The code will do exactly what you told it to do.

Comment: If there's a difference, one best starts with the most urgent/important task, possibly even having three separeate or a nested loops to complete all of the urgent work first. If there isn't – well, read/write is is somehow the natural order, or have you heard about a write/read failure or an OI error (I -> input -> reading, O analogously)? Might be due to the fact that most applications first get some input, process it and then produce some output from. And the error? '*Ah, sure there was something, let's append it*'. Error handling is surprisingly often neglected or even forgotten at all...

Comment: as long at the source of the conditions  `interestedevents` is not changed, it makes no difference in which order the conditions/events are handled